# JFrame and Graphic's Depth (Java)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paint

Well, he're is my problem:

I'am tryng to draw a grid using java graphics into a JFrame. But when i do, the grid overlays the components of the JFrame (JTextFields, Buttons, etc), i tried writting the "super.paint(g)" at the end of the paint method but when i do, the grid doesn't appears.

He're is the code:

```
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                    super.paint(g);
                    g.setColor(Color.PINK);
                    g.drawLine(0, 240, 640, 240);
                    g.drawLine(320,0,320,480);
                    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
                    for (int i=1; i<24; i++){
                        g.drawLine(0, i*20, 640, i*20);
                    }

            }
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: 1) Don't extend `JFrame` 2) Do custom painting in a `JComponent` or `JPanel`. 3) For those components, override `paintComponent(Graphics)` (or alternate to 2 & 3, draw the rendering to a `BufferedImage`) 4) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create yourself a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`).  Override it's `paintComponent` method and do your grid drawing there (don't forget to call `super.paintComponent`).
2. When you create your `JFrame`, set the panel as the content pane for the frame - ie `frame.setContentPane(new GridPane())`
3. Continue adding components to the frame as normal.

It is unadvised to override the `paint` methods of top level containers like `JFrame`.  They contain a lot of sub components that can interfere with your painting and it is very easy to simply screw up the paint process.

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer!!

I got the point, but now, i don't know why only appears the grid D:

Excuse bothering, he're is the code: [link] (http://pastie.org/6233010)

Thanks Again!

Comment: You have to set the content pane BEFORE you add anything the frame.  Change the content pane removes the old and replaces with new, taking any preexisting components wit it.